# parsing a JSON file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is a file (data.json) containing data formated in JSON :

```
{
  [
    {"nom" : "marteau" , "desc" : "pour en enfoncer des clous" , "qte" : "87" , "prix" : "9"},
    {"nom" : "cle de 12" , "desc" : "pour les boulons du camion" , "qte" : "25" , "prix" : "12"}
  ] 
}
```

I try to parse these data in JavaScript this way :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> catalogue outillage </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="oXHR.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function request(callback) {
                var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
                        callback(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }

                xhr.open("GET", "data.json", true);
                xhr.send();
            }

            function readData(oData) {              
                var catalogue = JSON.parse(oData);
                document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML = catalogue[0].nom;
                document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = catalogue[0].desc;
                document.getElementById("qte").innerHTML = catalogue[0].qte;
                document.getElementById("prix").innerHTML = catalogue[0].prix;  
            }

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>Name</label> : <label id = "nom"></label><br>
            <label>Description</label> : <label id = "desc"></label><br>
            <label>Quantité</label> : <label id = "qte"></label><br>
            <label>Prix</label> : <label id = "prix"></label><br>
            <button onclick="request(readData)">Afficher json</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, xhr.responseText seem to be void.

@epascarello I receive this message in developer console : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

@ShanRobertson I removed the first set of curly braces. But that doesn't work.

I've found the mistake : I removed the first set of form tag

Thanks for all

Comment: What do you see when you look at the request in the network panel/developer console?

Comment: so in fact it's not a JSON parsing problem at all, but an AJAX problem...

Comment: Your JSON doesn't validate. Try here: http://jsonlint.com/ or here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Why don't use jQuery for your HTTP request? That would make it easier than dealing with low level APIs. Nobody writes XMLHttpRequests manually anymore.

Comment: @alcfeoh Because not everyone includes jQuery....

Comment: jQuery, Angular, React... We're in 2015...

Comment: @alcfeoh How can you make that claim lol. I never use jquery and anytime i need to make a request I do it this way.

Comment: @ShanRobertson and how many old browsers does your code fail to work on?  [not that I in anyway endorse supporting old browsers.     Or MSIE...]

Comment: none, and I support back to ie8. I usually write native js and only use something like angular with the project requires a framework. have you ever seen this site? http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ it was a great tool for getting me off jquery.

Comment: @ShanRobertson I read the page, and was not impressed. But that's a discussion for chat. After abusing jQuery for years, and reading that page, I will continue to abuse jQuery for many years to come and will continue to recommend other poeple abuse it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't valid. You just need to remove the first set of curly braces.

```
[
    {
        "nom": "marteau",
        "desc": "pour en enfoncer des clous",
        "qte": "87",
        "prix": "9"
    },
    {
        "nom": "cle de 12",
        "desc": "pour les boulons du camion",
        "qte": "25",
        "prix": "12"
    }
]
```

Other than that your code looks fine.

Comment: Thief! But an upvote anyway, I didn't post this as an answer myself because I was hoping by linking him to the validators he would figure it out himself.